# will ubuntu work after my windows 7 be inactivated?

Tags: system-installation

I have Windows 7 Home Premium currently installed on my laptop, which is going to become inactive in next 20 days. My question is if: I have a partition in the C: drive, and then install Ubuntu with flash drive, can I still use Ubuntu once Windows 7 deactivates?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

The activation state of Windows will not have any effect on Ubuntu. So, yes, you will be able to use Ubuntu just like you can right now.

Answer (score 2):

Without a shadow of a doubt: yes, you will be able to use Ubuntu and format you disc after it runs out.

---

Microsoft uses software on your machine to check if your OS is validated. It will not run when you do not use Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu will work. For installing Ubuntu first from windows7 disk management shrink your C drive more than 20GB.Then try to install ubuntu as along with windows7, ubuntu will use the unallocated free space(20GB) which was created earlier using windows disk management. Then you will not face any problem. If you can't shrink C drive using windows disk management then use EaseUs partition master in windows7 for shrinking C drive more than 20GB.The link for Easeus partition master:http://www.filehippo.com/download_easeus_partition_master_home/